# Troubleshooting rotation with curve having Vector handle type

Tags: geometry-nodes

This is good:

[image]

This is not, notice the rotation is not following the curve as good as it should (Handle type is changed to Vector):

[image]

This is the node setup:

[image]

Is there a clean solution to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because input curve has only 4 points and Curve to Points node will interpolate values between curve points.

Simple solution would be using Resample Curve and use curve tangent to align rotation:

[image]

Another way if you want a "correct" rotation on the corners you can use this setup:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you mute the "Curve to Points" node and/or enter Edit Mode, you can see the input geometry has 4 points. If you additionally use "Align Euler to Vector" to align $Z$ to tangent, you can see the tangents calculated for those points:

[image]

The middle (non-endpoint) tangents are themselves interpolations of both line segments connected to those points, as marked by blue and aqua arrows.

Apparently when you convert the spline to a different number of points, tangents and normals, rather than being recalculated, are interpolated just as radius or custom attributes. So to recalculate them, resample the curve in a separate step:

[image]

An alternative setup for Higgsas' "correct" [it's his quotes, I'm not being rude] solution, you may consider something like this, it may actually be worse, but you may find it easier to reason about or adjust for your needs:

[image]

⚠ Edit: I just now noticed the input is a bezier with a resolution causing many more than 3 splines being produced after the *to mesh → split → to curve* chain, so be careful with this setup! As an apology here's a solution much closer to the one of Higgsas, but I added the aligning to normal as well, to more properly emulate the *Curve to Points: Rotation* socket. No idea you won't run into **problems with normal interpolation**, however, maybe it should be obtained in a smarter way…

[image]